# How do I get debugging information from NGINX about the cause of a "no live upstream" 502 error?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Under heavy load, the app I'm reverse-proxying to fails in some way that causes NGINX to return 502 errors. However, the logging in both the backend app and NGINX is lacking.

Specifically, NGINX simply says `no live upstreams while connecting to $UPSTREAM`, without any other log lines indicating why it considers the backend dead. I'd like to NGINX to help in debugging, by  giving me a reason when it classifies an upstream as dead (is the backend closing connections? refusing connections? returning some specific HTTP code?).

Is there any option that will give me what I'm looking for here, or some other way of getting insight into NGINX's decisions?